# PAM Errors in auth.log [Debian Squeeze]

Tags: security, authentication, debian-squeeze, pam, documentation

Based on the the [Securing Debian](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/securing-debian-howto/ch4.en.html) article on debian.org, I added the following to `/etc/pam.d/other`.

```
auth     required       pam_securetty.so
auth     required       pam_unix_auth.so
auth     required       pam_warn.so
auth     required       pam_deny.so
account  required       pam_unix_acct.so
account  required       pam_warn.so
account  required       pam_deny.so
password required       pam_unix_passwd.so
password required       pam_warn.so
password required       pam_deny.so
session  required       pam_unix_session.so
session  required       pam_warn.so
session  required       pam_deny.so
```

After I entered these, as the article suggested, I started getting errors in `/var/log/auth.log`

E.g.

```
PAM unable to dlopen(/lib/security/pam_unix_session.so): /lib/security/pam_unix_session.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
PAM adding faulty module: /lib/security/pam_unix_session.so
```

**Is the configuration mentioned in the above article still relevant in Debian Squeeze?**

Comment: Figured I'd leave this question up in case anyone else has a brain fart like I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Debian Squeeze, the following files no longer exist in `/lib/security`

- `pam_unix_auth.so`
- `pam_unix_acct.so`
- `pam_unix_passwd.so`
- `pam_unix_session.so`

In the `/etc/pam.d/other` file, there is already the following:

```
@include common-auth
@include common-account
@include common-password
@include common-session
```

The files that no longer exist in `/lib/security` have been replaced as follows:

- `pam_unix_auth.so` is now taken care of by `/etc/pam.d/common-auth`
- `pam_unix_acct.so` is now taken care of by
  `/etc/pam.d/common-account`
- `pam_unix_passwd.so` is now taken care of by
  `/etc/pam.d/common-password`
- `pam_unix_session.so` is now taken care of by
  `/etc/pam.d/common-session`